# raise ImproperlyConfigured, exc_info[1], exc_info[2]

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

I created a django (1.6.1) project and using mongodb with it. when I ran the `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to start server it gives me the following error

```
  File "D:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 129, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2186, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2169, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2158, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1209, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1133, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1432, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1537, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1497, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django_mongodb_engine\base.py", line 234
    raise ImproperlyConfigured, exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[django-mongodb-engine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mongodb-engine) does not support Python 3.x.

> Categories
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5
> Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
> Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
> ```

### Meaning of the error:

Syntax for the [`raise` statement](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) changed in Python 3.x. `raise expression, expression, expression` syntax is not valid in Python 3.x.

```
>>> raise ValueError, 'msg'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    raise ValueError, 'msg'
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> raise ValueError('msg')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: msg
```

Comment: how to use mongo db in python 3

Comment: @MdHasiburRahaman, There's a package called [`django-mongodb-engine-py3`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mongodb-engine-py3/).